# I have some string data that are in <> that I would like to convert to a list

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, string

The string comes in as `"<item1><item2><item3>"`

I would like to convert it to ['item1','item2','item3']

I was thinking of using string.split('><') and then stripping out the first < and the last >.

But this wouldn't work well if the string has things in front or after it or if there is a space in between the '>' and the '<'. Is there another way?

edit:

The specific string has the following format:

```
Some text
<item1><item2><item3> some more text
some text <item4> some text
```

It does work with re.findall, which returns

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4']
```

Which is exactly what I wanted. So thanks all.

Comment: Add a few examples of "strings in front" etc... so we have a better feel for what you need. Can these strings have spaces in them? Can they have ">" or "<" in them?

Comment: `[val for val in re.split("[<>]+", some_string) if val]` may do it.

Comment: This post doesn't have enough information for an answer. Lets close until more is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regular expression if your strings (`item1`, `item2`, etc.) don't contain a `<` or `>`

Regex: (Try it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8Paf7Z/1))

```
<(.*?)>
```

Explanation:

```
<       Match a literal <
 (   )  Capturing group
  .*?   Match any character, any number of times using a lazy match
      > Match a literal >
```

To run this with python, do:

```
import re

s = '<item1><item2><item3>'
re.findall('<(.*?)>', s)
```

Which gives your expected output

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

Comment: This could work well but the poster adds _But this wouldn't work well if the string has things in front or after it_ without showing us examples or telling us whether these extra strings should be part of the list. Until OP decides to engage, its all just a guess.

Comment: The string is more like ```<item1><item2> some text <item3> some more text```
I just need item1, item2, and item3

Answer (score 3):

Use regex with a capturing group `()`

```
import re

s = '<item1><item2><item3>'
re.findall('<(\w+)>', s)
```

Output

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```